# I need a desktop clock app

Tags: open-source, shell-extension

I am looking for a clock app/widget/ectension which will be always on my screen, irrespective of my window size or type, I want the time [hh:mm] always on my screen, may be on a corner with an opacity of 40-60%.

Comment: For what OS/Desktop do you need it? And by "always on my screen" you mean "always visible" – like, if your application window is full-size, the clock displays on top of it, or the clock limits the space for full-screen?

Comment: Windows has this built-in: it shows the time in the task bar. Just make sure the task bar is always shown.

Answer (score -1):

I use [SlickRun](https://www.bayden.com/slickrun/) for this purpose.  Its primary purpose is to launch programs using user-selected abbreviations.  I've been using it for years.  You can configure the opacity and date and time display any way you like.